# How to Create multiple classes in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, class, vector

Create 200 classes (think about an efficient way to do this), each class will contain the following public members:

a. Name - Which will hold first and last name

b. Address- which will hold the street number and name

c. Phone - which will hold the phone number

The user will be able to enter the information for between 1 and 200 individuals(determined by the user).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class information {

public:
    //member variables go here


};

int main() {

    char answer = 'Y';
    int i = 0; //why is this here?

    //instantiate your classes here


    do {

        cout << "This is the address book enter the first and last name    "
            << "address and phone number: \n";
        cout << "Name (First and Last): ";

        //will need a 'cin' to store the name (hint: use getline)


        cout << "\n\nAddress: ";
        //address


        cout << "\n\nPhone Number: ";
        //phone


        i++;

        cout << "Enter another person?  Y/N: ";
        //answer Y or N



    } while ;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Create 200 classes or 200 instances of a class (one of these things is not like the other)?

Comment: Is this a homework? Is "Create 200 classe" the original request? That looks wrong, I bet the task should better read "create 200 objects".

Comment: You need an array of size 200 or a vector to accomplish this.

Comment: @WernerHenze it is homework, and it definitely says create 200 classes

Comment: @Conner a `class` is a declaration. To create 200 `class`, you need to have 200 declarations of `class NAME { /* ... */ }` that would get compiled.

Comment: @Conner Then greetings to the one that gave you the homework. 200 classes is nonsense. `class A1 { ... };` is one class, `class A2 { ... };` is a second class. 200 of them is a lot.One could argue about templates, but that is strange. And the task also says that the user inputs the number up to 200, so that can only mean objects (instances of a class, like `class A {...}; A a1; A a2;`). The homework is wrongly formulated.

Answer (score 0):

```
class information {

public:
    //member variables go here
    string name, address,phone;

};
```

And in the main method, write

```
information info[200];
```

This creates 200 objects of class information. To set values, you need to run a loop like:

```
for(i=0;i<200;i++)
{
    cin>>info[i].name>>info[i].address>>info[i].phone;
}
```